# get nested python dict key and values and place in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I loop this nested python dictionary and build a list for all the values for aggregate, S1, S2, S3, and S4. A couple things to note aggregate will always exist in all these various keys but the other keys S1 to S4 can be dynamic in this example I have S1 to S4 but its possible this could be S1 to S10 as I am passed this information from a server. Also its possible any of these keys such as v4_acl could look like the key PNC where all the data except aggregate exist.

My end result was to have something like

```
S1List = [10,10,10,10,10]
S2List = [20,20,20,20,20]
S3List = [30,30,30,30,30]
S4List = [40,40,40,40,40]
aggregateList = [100,100,100,100,100]
```

## My dict

```
{
    "OuterKey": {
        "v4_acl": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 10,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 30,
            "S4": 40
        },
        "v6_acl": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 10,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 30,
            "S4": 40
        },
        "v4_qos": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 10,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 30,
            "S4": 40
        },
        "v6_nf": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 10,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 30,
            "S4": 40
        },
        "baseline": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 10,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 30,
            "S4": 40
        },
        "PNC": {
            "aggregate": 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be fairly simple to do with a `for` loop. Did you try something that did not work? Can you post that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use append to a dictionary using `setdefault` to group the items while looping through the `values()` and `keys()`. Something like:

```
res = {}
for k  in d['OuterKey'].values():
    for g in k:
        res.setdefault(g, []).append(k[g])
```

in the end `res` will be a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'aggregate': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0],
 'S1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
 'S2': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
 'S3': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
 'S4': [40, 40, 40, 40, 40]}
```